# System design of a multi PCB project

Tags: pcb, system

I am currently supervising the design of a system made of several PCBs and cables and I am looking for a tool to help me maintain an easy overview of the interfaces.

I have been searching around and the only two extreme options I could find are the following:

1. on one hand, there are the very complex and expensive industrial tools (for example, Xpedition System Designer) that allow not only to do what I need, but much more. The problem with this type of tool is that it has usually a high learning curve and it does a lot of things that I don't really need.
2. on the other end of the spectrum, a very simple tool like any drawing tool could be enough to draw a block diagram and keep track of the relevant information. The problem here is that there is no automation whatsoever in case I want to export/attach some information to a board.

Do any of you know of a tool which is "in-between"? Something where I can define the interface between two boards and add information to the interfaces?

For example: on board A I have a connector (with gender, number of pins, manufacturer, etc..) and on board B I have the mating one (opposite gender, same number of pins, manufacturer, etc...); I would like to be able to export in some form the information and, ideally, even be able to do some checks.

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't really a valid EE question plus, you are asking for product recommendations (off topic). I'd use excel. I mean it's decent for parts list and you can link data sheets etc..

Comment: Apologies for being off-topic, I am not a frequent reader of this stackexchange and did not carefully read the rules, my fault!